# Enter text into executable file immediately after it's run

Tags: linux, terminal, executable

I have an executable file `file` that I am running by typing `./file` into the terminal. When the program runs, I have to type in the text "code". However, the time taken to type it, or paste it into the terminal, results in the program saying "sorry, you took too long!".

I am tying to send the text "code" to the executable file when I run it, as therefore it would be inputted into the program immediately once it's run.

I've tried `./file; "code"` and `./file && "code"` but have had no luck - the program still wants an input.

Comment: Are you looking for `echo "code" | ./file` ?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Brilliant! That's it, thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the pipeline feature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix) :

```
echo "code" | ./file
```